# Send Multi dimensional array to web services in post format

Tags: php, web-services

I want to send a request to a web services, and the data I want to send to that webservices is a multi dimesional array.

This is the array:

```
$array = array( array(
                        'search_product' => 'syntha-6 isolate One',
                        'search_product1' => 'syntha-6 isolate Two',
                        'search_product2' => 'syntha-6 isolate Three',
                        'search_product3' => 'syntha-6 isolate Four',
                        'search_product4' => 'syntha-6 isolate Five',
                        'search_brand1' => 'bsn',
                        'search_brand2' => 'BSN'
                      ),
                array(
                        'search_product' => 'syntha-6 isolate Six',
                        'search_product1' => 'syntha-6 isolate Seven',
                        'search_product2' => 'syntha-6 isolate Eight',
                        'search_product3' => 'syntha-6 isolate Nine',
                        'search_product4' => 'syntha-6 isolate Ten',
                        'search_brand1' => 'bsn',
                        'search_brand2' => 'BSN'
                      ),
                array(
                        'search_product' => 'syntha-6 isolate H',
                        'search_product1' => 'syntha-6 isolate K',
                        'search_product2' => 'syntha-6 isolate L',
                        'search_product3' => 'syntha-6 isolate M',
                        'search_product4' => 'syntha-6 isolate N',
                        'search_brand1' => 'bsn',
                        'search_brand2' => 'BSN'
                      ),
            );
```

And here's the curl code that I am using to send the data to webservices.

```
$send_data = array('data'=>$array);
$content   = json_encode($send_data);
$url       = "http://52.53.227.143/API_test1.php";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
print_r($response);
```

And this is the code I am using on the webservices sever:

```
$post       = json_decode($_POST);
$json_array = json_encode($post);

echo $json_array;
```

But its not working for me.

Please suggest me how should I accomplish this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

send the array as json and with json http header

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($array));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already tired that solution. Its not working for me.

Comment: have you checked the results with these things`$output = curl_exec( $ch );$err=curl_errno( $ch );$errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );$header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );`

Comment: Its giving me follow error:
Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/API_test1.php on line 23

null

Here is my webserivce code:
$content    = json_decode($_POST,true);
$json_array = json_encode($content);
echo $json_array;

Comment: Anyone with any solution ?

Comment: can you try `$postdata = file_get_contents('php://input');` instead of $_POST